# getting the column name

Tags: sql, oracle

I've the below html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="new" method="post" action="GetR.jsp">
<div class="Main">
  <table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Units</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Units" id="Units"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Type</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ProdT" id="ProdT"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hours</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="hours" id="hours"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the below data base table

[image]

here actually when the user enters the number of units and hours and product type(product type is same as database table name) based on the input, the output should be the column names(whether it is achieved, exceeded or far exceeded) . please let me know how can i write a query for it.

for example the given row.

we entered the units as 1, and if the hours is 8(4.1hrs-8hrs), it should show `No.of.Hours for Achieved`, if hours is 4(2.1hrs-4hrs) it should show `Exceeded` and if 2(below 2 hrs) it should show  `Far-Exceeded`.

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using(Oracle, MS SQL etc.)?

Comment: Hi @AnatoliiGabuza, i use Oracle, also there is a small change in my question, I've updated it. Thanks